# Rails 4: multi-level includes and conditions

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've read the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) docs on this and have googled already, but the examples I've come across don't work.  I'm sure this is a duplicate question, but none of the current ones work so I'm asking it again.

This is my model setup, 2 levels deep:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offices
end

class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
  has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
end
```

I need to find all the `companies` that have associated `contacts` with a given `user_id` value.

```
user_id = 1
Company.includes(offices: :contacts).where("contacts.user_id = ?", user_id)
```

I keep getting an error: `TinyTds::Error: The multi-part identifier "contacts.user_id" could not be bound.`

The only table with a `user_id` is `contacts`.  Unfortunately I have to use MS SQL Server as the DB, hence the reason I'm using `TinyTds`.

I'm assuming my Rails AR syntax is incorrect, but the API docs are rather confusing to me on multi-level queries like this.

Comment: Is it contacts or contact?

Comment: Try `Company.includes(offices: [:contacts]).where("contacts.user_id = ?", user_id)`

Comment: @TTeeple: it is `contacts`. I updated the original post with the fix.

Comment: @Pavan: I tried that query and I still get the `multi-part identifier "contacts.user_id" could not be bound.` error.